# Dropdown menu opened on pageload ONLY on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I created simple CSS menu with only one dropdown submenu, which has to be opened on pageload ONLY on homepage, and keep it closed by default on rest of site pages.

I managed to set dropdown menu to be opened by default on pageload with Javascript (and closed onclick), and this works perfectly.

```
    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="divBg">

        <!-- BUTTON 1 -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtnMain" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display=='none' ? document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display='' : document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display ='none';">Dropdown categories</button>

            <!-- BUTTON 1 DROPDOWN CONTENT -->
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown">
                <a href=#>Dropdown link 1</a>
                <a href=#>Dropdown link 2</a>
                <a href=#>Dropdown link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- BUTTON 2 -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Category 2</button>
        </div>

        <!-- BUTTON 3 -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Category 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But is there solution to have dropdown opened ONLY on homepage, and closed by default on all other pages?

Comment: I think we need the javascript that opens the dropdown menu on pageload too. But I think you can check if is homepage assigning a class to the body in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do it by add css class:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and then in JavaScript you can base on page that is loaded:

```
if (window.location.pathname !== '/') {
    document.querySelector('.dropdown').classList.add('is-hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this works perfectly! Only has to be applied to .dropdown-content class, because .dropdown hides button also.

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using seperate html files you could just remove the javascript?

But I'm guessing, although not specified you're including the dropdown file in your other pages you can use a javascript function with location.pathname, to check what the filename is and only run it then

This as your onclick.

```
onclick="foo()"
```

This is the function to go at the top in a script area or script file.

```
function foo(){
    if(location == "http://foobar.com"){
        //Code to open your drop down
    }  
}
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your body tag a class of 'home' and then add the following CSS.

```
body.home .dropdown{display:block;}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Huh, this should work perfectly, changing display:none into display:block only on homepage, but it doesn't work in my case. 

I am using Shopware e-commerce platform, would there be a problem in not recognizing homepage as "home"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code.

```
#dropdown
{ 
  display: none; 
}
body.home #dropdown
{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an id and a class to the body like this:

```
<body id="home" class="home">
...
</body>
```

And then I would check if body has this selector:

```
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

if(hasClass(document.getElementById("home"), "test")){
    //do something
}
```